# Iterating IQueryable in the foreach loop

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Having such code

```
foreach (Order order in dbContext.Orders)
{
    // some operations
}
```

Are Orders fetched from db after each iteration?
Is there any need to call `ToList()` on `dbContext.Orders`?

Comment: The implementation of `ToList` will likely do exactly this, adding items to a list in the loop body.

Comment: If you are interested in what it submits to the database, you should run a SQL Trace. But @spender is correct.

Answer (score 1):

It does not load one order per one iteration of the foreach loop. Your code loads the entire query result into memory when enumerated.

No need to `List()` your `IQueryable<Order>` type in case you use `foreach` on them. You query is materilized when you invoke `ToList()` or when you use `foreach` loop.

See more info about [Query Execution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/query-execution)